# Unexpected token RactJS

Tags: reactjs

./src/index.js
  Line 26:  Parsing error: Unexpected token in reactjs.

My code,

```
fetch('https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs.json')
    .then((result) => {
      // Get the result
      // If we want text, call result.text()
      return result.json();
    }).then((jsonResult) => {
      // Do something with the result
      console.log(jsonResult);
    })
  }
```

I tired to run a code error will be show,

```
Failed to compile
./src/index.js
  Line 26:  Parsing error: Unexpected token

  24 |   }
  25 | 
> 26 |   fetch('https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs.json')
     |         ^
  27 |     .then((result) => {
  28 |       // Get the result
  29 |       // If we want text, call result.text()
```

Comment: You most likely have a typo in your code. The code snippet that you sent seems ok but it might be something wrong above that. If you put together a basic codesandbox with your entire component it might be easier to track the error.

Comment: post the whole file

Comment: the error will cleared. now another error on here, https://textuploader.com/1d2hg the error on content type. error(has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field content-type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.)